# Error when using system classloader with grapes

Tags: java, groovy

I'm writing a simple Groovy program with Java that reads something from the database:

```
@Grab('com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.1.0')
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy', module='groovy-sql', version='2.4.6')

import groovy.sql.Sql

def db = [url: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE",
          user: 'user_kshitiz', password: 'a', driver: 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver']
def sql = Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, db.driver)
```

However, this gives me a `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found` error.
So I configure grapes to use system classloader:

```
@Grapes([
        @Grab('com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.1.0'),
        @GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)
])
```

This too results in following error:

```
Information:Groovyc: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$518.<init>(java.lang.String, org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass, java.lang.Class, [Ljava.lang.Class;)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2849)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1718)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GeneratedMetaMethod$Proxy.createProxy(GeneratedMetaMethod.java:92)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GeneratedMetaMethod$Proxy.proxy(GeneratedMetaMethod.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GeneratedMetaMethod$Proxy.isValidMethod(GeneratedMetaMethod.java:68)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMethodInternal(MetaClassImpl.java:3172)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:3134)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getMethodWithCachingInternal(MetaClassImpl.java:1330)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.createPojoCallSite(MetaClassImpl.java:3367)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createPojoSite(CallSiteArray.java:132)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallSite(CallSiteArray.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.grab(GrapeIvy.groovy:271)
    at groovy.grape.Grape.grab(Grape.java:167)
    at groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation.visit(GrabAnnotationTransformation.java:378)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor$3.call(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:321)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:931)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:593)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovyCompilerWrapper.compile(GroovyCompilerWrapper.java:58)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.DependentGroovycRunner.runGroovyc(DependentGroovycRunner.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovycRunner.intMain2(GroovycRunner.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc.runGroovycInThisProcess(InProcessGroovyc.java:156)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc.access$000(InProcessGroovyc.java:51)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc$1.call(InProcessGroovyc.java:85)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc$1.call(InProcessGroovyc.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How do I create a database connection in Groovy?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Oracle drivers are not publicly accessable in Maven Central. You have some options though:

1. Get access to some non public Maven repository containing Oracle JDBC drivers
2. Manually download Oracle JDBC driver from Oracle site, import it into your local Maven repository or Local artifactory-like service, and include this repository in your build script

Answer (score 0):

JDBC drivers are available on Oracle Maven repository.  Please follow the instructions in this [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides) for more details.